# react router - properly using links inside nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to have a blog feed that when a user clicks on any blog post, the route changes to display only the individual post + header. This uses some nested routes with react-router and all [tutorials](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/) show how to display dynamic data further down the nest, not how to override the parent route.

Blog component:

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const posts = [
       { id: 1, title: "Post 1", slug: "post-1" },
       { id: 2, title: "Post 2", slug: "post-2" },
       { id: 3, title: "Post 3", slug: "post-3" }
    ];
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => (
            <>
              <SidebarLeft />
              <Feed />
              <SidebarRight />
            </>
          )}
        />
        {/* I need to somehow pass the postTitle & postSlug props by only having access to the slug url param */}
        <Route path="/articles/:postSlug" component={Post} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Feed component:

```
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() { 
    // gets posts from props
    var jsonPosts = this.props.posts;
    var arr = [];
    Object.keys(jsonPosts).forEach(function(key) {
      arr.push(jsonPosts[key]);
    });
    return (
      <>
        {arr.map(post => (
          <Post
            key={post.id}
            postSlug={post.slug}
            postTitle={post.title}
          />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Post component:

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.postTitle}</h1>
      <Link to={'/articles/' + this.props.postSlug}>{this.props.postSlug}</Link>
    );
  }
}
```

index.jsx

```
// renders all of react
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Blog} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oxrvrnr27q)

The problem I have is the `Feed` works just fine, and all the `Post` links work. It's as soon as I click any of the posts, react doesn't know which `Post` I'm trying to access.

This is where I'm not sure how to proceed since all tutorials I've found simply show the `Post` component nested further down. How do I tell react which post I'm trying to view and have it render the appropriate route in the `Blog` component?

Comment: You have no `Router` component in the code in your question. Do you have one outside of `Blog`?

Comment: @Tholle yes I do. Edited question to include it, although I don't think it is the source of the problem.

Comment: What happens if you click on the the `Link` components in one of the `Post` components? Nothing?

Comment: @Tholle It goes to "/articles/:postSlug" but displays a blank page because the route in `Blog` doesn't know which `postSlug` prop to pass. I know I could pass it through `{match.params.postSlug}` but I actually need to pass more info about the post that I don't want in the URL. I'll edit the question again to include this bit because I realized its importance.

Comment: If you want to re-use the `Post` component you use in `Feed` for the standalone route `/articles/:postSlug`, you most likely need to fetch the post data from the slug inside the `Post` component instead of passing it as props. Could you create e.g. a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) illustrating your issue?

Comment: @Tholle here it is, thanks for taking the time! https://codesandbox.io/s/oxrvrnr27q

Comment: I think it works fine, but you just have to add some custom logic to pass down the data to the component, [e.g. like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3wz9qkl5p).

Comment: @Tholle That's it! Solved it, thank you! I've edited my question to include the CodeSandbox code. If you put yours as an answer, I'll gladly accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, but you have to add some additional logic to pass down the right props when `/articles/:postSlug` match.

**Example**

```js
class Blog extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const posts = [
      { id: 1, title: "Post 1", slug: "post-1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Post 2", slug: "post-2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Post 3", slug: "post-3" }
    ];

    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <Feed posts={posts} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/articles/:postSlug"
            render={props => {
              const post = posts.find(p => p.slug === props.match.params.postSlug);

              if (!post) {
                return null;
              }
              return <Post {...props} postTitle={post.title} postSlug={post.slug} />;
            }}
          />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```